# Boot repair failed - no GRUB found - what now?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub, boot-loader

So I've installed Mint from a bootable USB. All seems to go well. However when I then go to boot into the install I'm greeted with a flashing cursor and nothing more.

After a bit of internet searching I came across the 'hold shift to force GRUB start', but that didn't do anything.

I checked the drive using gparted and there is definitely a boot partition on there.

Then I came across the boot-repair thing in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194135/linux-mint-17-1-mate-blinking-cursor-error) which I ran. However it failed at the end saying there was still no GRUB present. The terminal output was:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  linux-signed-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 3.13.0.65.71)     but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I manually installed linux-headers-generic but I still get the same error.

So now I'm a bit lost as to what to do...
Any suggestions?

The drive in question is a 120GB SSD Vertex 3, and it's in a Workstation computer with a Xeon chip and MoBo with a Asus GTX960 graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. 
Found a solution. I had to change the SSD's access method or something from 'AHCI' to the 'compatible' setting. This fixed the problem.